# how can i create object of collectionview Cell in delegate sizeForItemAtIndexPath in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Like in Objective we can get object of CollectionViewCell as below. have some issue with Swift:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
DatasetCell *datasetCell = (DatasetCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
(DatasetCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
datasetCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor skyBlueColor]; 
}
```

my swift code is :

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let datasetCell: DatasetCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DatasetCell

    datasetCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
}
```

Comment: Where is your swift code ?

Answer (score 1):

To translate that method into swift it would look like this

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let datasetCell =  collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath: indexPath) as DatasetCell
    datasetCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

}
```